# Wordpress - Execute a PHP function on Button Click

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have a custom function called revokeCard() that revokes a currently viewed collectible Card (of which duplicates can be obtained) and awards Points to the current user, thus creating an action that simulates the user 'selling' the Card.

Note: Cards are an achievement type (custom post type) added using the Wordpress plugin, Gamipress.

Here's the function first:

```
function revokeCard(){
                  
$achievement_id = get_the_ID();
$user = get_current_user_id();
$points = 1000;
$points_type = 'fan-point';

gamipress_revoke_achievement_to_user($achievement_id, $user);                     
gamipress_award_points_to_user( $user->ID, $points, $points_type ); 

}
```

The function is actually working, but I want it to run when a user clicks on a 'Sell Card' button which is on the single template for these Cards. I did try this code, which was modified from another snippet found online:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="revoke" id="revoke" value="Sell Card" /><br/>
</form>

<?php

function revokeCurrent()
{
   revokeCard();
}

if(array_key_exists('revoke',$_POST)){
   revokeCurrent();
}

?>
```

Technically, this works. The page refreshes instantly after pressing the button, which I'm okay with because I want the user to then see the new count for how many of this Card this own and their new points balance. However, it's almost like it refreshes too quickly and the updated values are not shown. But if I return to the post I can see that the function has worked and the user has earned the points and had 1 of the Card revoked. If I click Refresh in the browser I also then get a warning that the form data will be resubmitted, which means they'll continue to lose Cards/Receive Points unintentionally each time they refresh, which I want to prevent. So I'd prefer to get this working with a button element rather than a form if possible.

All the methods I've seen around relating to buttons rather than forms suggests ajax, but I do actually want to refresh the page, so I don't know if I necessarily need it to be ajax.

Whichever method is best, I'd really appreciate any help in achieving this functionality.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: _Where_ did you put the code that calls `revokeCurrent`? It probably executes _after_ the data for the current page has already been requested from the database. Try putting it into the `functions.php` of the theme maybe. And if that does not work either - then you will need to go and have a look at what _hook_ to bind this functionality to, to get it executed in a place in the page generation sequence before the data to display gets fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input. I managed to solve this by adding a header(location) argument, while also adding a query arg of status=sold so that a custom message could be rendered when the Card has been sold. The full code is below:

```
<?php 

$achievement_id = get_the_ID();

$sale_price=get_field('card_sale_price');

$earned = gamipress_has_user_earned_achievement( get_the_ID(), $user_id ); ?>

<?php if($earned): ?>

   <form method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="revoke" id="revoke" value="Sell Card" /><br/>
   </form>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php

   function revokeCurrent()
   {
      revokeCard();
   }

   if(array_key_exists('revoke',$_POST)){
      revokeCurrent();
      header("location:index.php?status=sold"); 
   }

?>

<?php if( $_GET['status'] == 'sold'): ?>

   <div class="card-sold-msg">
      You Sold This Card for <?php echo $sale_price; ?> Fan Points
   </div>
   
<?php endif; ?>
```

**header("location:index.php?status=sold");** was the only addition needed. The page now fully refreshes once the RevokeCard() function is actioned and the Card is sold/Points awarded as expected.